# Можно ли при использовании Laravel ,создавать таблицы через phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

Не сломается ли в Laravel ничего ,если я вместо миграций буду создавать таблицы в phpmyadmin?

Comment: Скорее всего до того момента, как кто-то начнет писать `php artisan migrate`. Ну а в общем, вот [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47787088/can-i-add-database-table-manually-in-laravel) на английском SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничего не сломается, миграции сделаны для удобства, с их помощью можно спокойно держать базы локальные и на проде в одном состояниии, чтобы не получилось что локально таблицу добавили, на проде забыли, если вам это не нужно - можете спокойно пользоваться phpmyadmin и не переживать.